# Is my kitten a girl or boy?

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

[image]

This sounds like a silly question but this is my first time owning a cat, and I know close to nothing. The kitten is estimated to be around 10 weeks old. I assumed my kitten was a girl but after looking closely, I'm second guessing myself and want to be sure.

I am sorry for the unpleasant picture but I felt it was the easiest way to get an opinion.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest asking an veterinarian.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a boy. The penis appears round in a kitten, the vulva will be slit like. Plus there is a scrotal sac between the penis and the anus. In girls the distance between the vulva and anus is shorter.

For more details and some images:

[Veterinary Advice Online - Sexing Kittens and Cats.](http://www.pet-informed-veterinary-advice-online.com/sexing-kittens.html)

[Determining Gender (Sex) of a Kitten](http://www.vetmed.wsu.edu/outreach/Pet-Health-Topics/categories/procedures/cats/determining-gender-(sex)-of-a-kitten)